# C# - How to decode UTF-8 String to Normal Strings or Emoji

Tags: c#-2.0

I storing my messages as utf-8 to preserve emoji
but how do I decode it again and show its original form
This is the Sample Message - %e2%9c%8c

```
  String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(contacts.getYourmessage(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: There are search engines Google, Bing,... try them out before asking like https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+decode+percent+encoded+utf8 or even https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%+equivalent+of+java+URLDecoder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is the Sample Message - %e2%9c%8c

It is url-encoded string. So you can

```
var str = WebUtility.UrlDecode("%e2%9c%8c");
```

which returns `✌`

Answer (score 0):

This is for swift:

```
var str = "%e2%9c%8c"
print(str.removingPercentEncoding)
```

Output:

```
Optional("✌")
```